# Googlemap widget doesn't dispose

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I have many view in my application. Two of them access the map view. and give him the localization and where we are going. When I click previous, to return, my GoogleMap widget's isn't remove and make my application bug. this is [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDjjl.png)

This is the code:

```
GoogleMapController? mapController; 
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

  Set<Marker> markers = Set(); 
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};


@override
  void dispose() {
    mapController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Géolocalisation"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        ),
        body: Stack(children: [
          GoogleMap(
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true, 
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: startLocation, 
              zoom: 14.0,
            ),
            markers: markers, 
            polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values), 
            mapType: MapType.normal, 
            onMapCreated: (controller) {
              if (mounted) {
                setState(() {
                  mapController = controller;
                });
                _location.onLocationChanged.listen((l) {
                  rotation = l.heading!;
                  startLocation = LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!);
                  _geolocalisation();
                  mapController?.animateCamera(
                    CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                      CameraPosition(
                          target: LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!),
                          zoom: 16,
                          bearing: l.heading!),
                    ),
                  );
                });
              }
            },
          ),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: Container(
                  child: Card(
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Text(
                        "Distance: " + distance.toStringAsFixed(2) + " KM ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              )))
        ]));
  }
```

I add return button but it doesn't solve the bug